# getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function setBg () {
 var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*17)+1;
 for(i = 1; i!=37; i++) {
  document.getElementById('"window'+i+'"').style.backgroundImage = "url('img/"+rand+".jpg')";
 }
}
```

```css
.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
 grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.container div {
 border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="setBg()">Start game</button>
 <div class="container">
  <div id="window1"></div>
  <div id="window2"></div>
  <div id="window3"></div>
  <div id="window4"></div>
  <div id="window5"></div>
  <div id="window6"></div>
  <div id="window7"></div>
  <div id="window8"></div>
  <div id="window9"></div>
  <div id="window10"></div>
  <div id="window11"></div>
  <div id="window12"></div>
  <div id="window13"></div>
  <div id="window14"></div>
  <div id="window15"></div>
  <div id="window16"></div>
  <div id="window17"></div>
  <div id="window18"></div>
  <div id="window19"></div>
  <div id="window20"></div>
  <div id="window21"></div>
  <div id="window22"></div>
  <div id="window23"></div>
  <div id="window24"></div>
  <div id="window25"></div>
  <div id="window26"></div>
  <div id="window27"></div>
  <div id="window28"></div>
  <div id="window29"></div>
  <div id="window30"></div>
  <div id="window31"></div>
  <div id="window32"></div>
  <div id="window33"></div>
  <div id="window34"></div>
  <div id="window35"></div>
  <div id="window36"></div>
 </div>




 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ошибка в document.getElementById('"window'+i+'"'), но не пойму что же не правельно

Comment: Замените `('"window'+i+'"')` на `('window' + i)`. Двойные кавычки в HTML коде не являются частью id - они являются границами значения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените `('"window' + i + '"')` на `('window' + i)`. Двойные кавычки в HTML коде не являются частью id - они являются границами значения атрибута

Пример:

```js
function setBg () {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 17) + 1;
    var url = "https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=text" + rand;
    var element = document.getElementById("window" + i);
    element.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}

.container div {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setBg()">Start game</button>
<div class="container">
  <div id="window1"></div>
  <div id="window2"></div>
  <div id="window3"></div>
  <div id="window4"></div>
</div>
```